Copying an excel file and immediately launching a userform within the new file
I have code to present the user with a simple userform with 2 textboxes. It then copies an excel file to a specific location on the server and names it appropriately per the user inputs. That part all works great. But now I want a userform from the newly-copied file to pop up for the user to start filling out and I'm stuck. I've tried a ton of different ways of calling the userform and all lead to errors. I've made certain that macros are enabled, trusted, etc. but I'm just not making any progress. Here's the existing code from the first userform 'OK' button:
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim jobNumber As String
    Dim customerCode As String
    Dim SourceFilePath As String
    Dim newFullPath As String
    Dim JobsFolder As String
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim fso As Object

    ' Get the user inputs
    jobNumber = TextBox1.Text
    customerCode = TextBox2.Text

    ' Ensure the inputs are not empty
    If jobNumber = "" Or customerCode = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter both the job number and customer code.", vbExclamation
        Me.Hide
        Me.Show
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Extract the part before the first hyphen
    JobsFolder = Split(jobNumber, "-")(0)

    ' Construct the new full path
    newFileName = "MASTER BOM " & jobNumber & " ASM 0.xlsm"
    folderPath = "\\pmw-fs1\Storage-PMW\Jobs\" & JobsFolder & " " & UCase(customerCode)
    newFullPath = folderPath & "\" & newFileName

    ' Check if the folder exists
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    If Not fso.FolderExists(folderPath) Then
        Dim response As VbMsgBoxResult
        response = MsgBox("The folder for """ & JobsFolder & " " & UCase(customerCode) & """ does not exist. Are you certain you want to create this folder?", vbYesNo + vbExclamation, "Folder Not Found")
        If response = vbYes Then
            ' Create the folder
            fso.CreateFolder folderPath
        Else
            ' Display the userform again with current inputs
            Me.Hide
            ' Re-fill the textboxes with the current inputs
            TextBox1.Text = jobNumber
            TextBox2.Text = UCase(customerCode)
            Me.Show
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    ' Get the current file path
    SourceFilePath = "\\pmw-fs1\Storage-PMW\Jobs\_Automation\MasterBomVBA\Master Bom Data.xlsm"

    ' Save a copy of the source workbook to the new location with the new name
    Workbooks.Open SourceFilePath
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs newFullPath
    ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

    ' Open the new file and set it as the active workbook
    Dim newWorkbook As Workbook
    Set newWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(newFullPath)
    newWorkbook.Activate
    
    InitialInput.Hide 'the 2-textbox userform
    TextBox1.Text = ""
    TextBox2.Text = ""
    
    ' Show the PartEntry userform from the new workbook
    newWorkbook.Application.Run "PartEntry.Show"
 
End Sub


Does this answer your question?

Add a macro on the source workbook
Sub PartEntryShow()
    PartEntry.Show
End Sub

then replace newWorkbook.Application.Run "PartEntry.Show" with
Call newWorkbook.PartEntryShow

this gives me a "run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method.

@Cptnamr7 where did you put the macro, on the workbook or a sheet or a module ?

it's in a module- for now. Eventually going to move everything to being an add-in the launch. The initial sheet-copy is run via module- press play. Which now that I think about it, may be creating an issue here with an open VBA window from the old file. (the launching macro is in a random unrelated workbook for now until I make it into an add-in)  Right now I have a module that is nothing more than "filecopyuserform.show" that I am using to trigger this whole thing. The PartEntry userform is in the source file and there is a module there that does nothing more than show it.

@Cptnamr7 Try putting the macro on ThisWorkbook in the source file or
if you want to put in a module use
Application.Run "'" & newWorkbook.Name & "'!Module1.PartEntryShow". Change module name as required.

the correct syntax to get the new macro to trigger is:
Application.Run "'" & newWorkbook.Name & "'!PartEntryFormShow"

